# How to append the data into JSON Format array in swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

How to append one new value in JSON array using the below format

https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NJC7eX-oU

In the above URL how to append the data letters array??

```
{
    "Letters": [
        {
            "Test1": [
                {
                    "Priority": 1,
                    "Description": "A"
                },
                {
                    "Priority": 2,
                    "Description": "B"
                }
            ],
            "Test2": [
                {
                    "Priority": 1,
                    "Description": "A"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are you specifically asking and what do you mean by "JSON array"? Is this a server side swift question or an iOS app question or something else?

Comment: server side swift question

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode it with

```
struct Root: Codable {
    var letters: [[String:[Test]]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case letters = "Letters"
    }
}

struct Test: Codable {
    let priority: Int
    let description: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case priority = "Priority"
        case description = "Description"
    }
}
```

---

```
do { 
    var res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)

    res.letters.append(["test3":[Test(priority: 6, description: "des")]])

    res.letters[0]["Test2"]?.append(Test(priority: 612, description: "des2"))

    let wer = try JSONEncoder().encode(res)

    let json = String(data: wer, encoding: .utf8)

    print(json)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how to insert "ObjectsHere" in the above code and how to append the value into Test2